# dojox.image.Gallery, undefined image source

Tags: javascript, xpages, dojo, lotus-domino

I have a little problem with dojo.
In my XPages application I want to implement an imageGallery with dojox.image.Gallery.

I've set up everything and my agent returns some JSON data, seems valid so far.

It's structure looks like this:

{ items: [
{
"thumb":"linktothumbnail",
"large":"linktolargepic",
"title":"whatever1",
"link" :"www.google.de"
},{... and so on...

URL to pics are valid, checked it.

Everything works, no error messages, except one. 
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.myserver.de/path/to/database.nsf/undefined"
The src attribute of my Thumbnailpicker is "undefined"

I've crawled the web, no results so far.

This is my code in the XPage:

```
<xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojox.image.Gallery"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore"></xp:dojoModule>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.parser"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:div id="Wrapper">
        Test

        <div jsId="imageItemStore" dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore"
            url="#{javascript:return facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + '/returnMemberDataJSON?OpenAgent';}">
        </div>  

        <div id="gallery1" dojoType="dojox.image.Gallery"  imageHeight="400" imageWidth="550">
            <script type="dojo/connect">
                var itemRequest = {
                    query: {},
                    count: 20
                };
                var itemNameMap = {
                    imageThumbAttr: "label",
                    imageLargeAttr: "name"
                };
                this.setDataStore(imageItemStore, itemRequest, itemNameMap);
            </script>
        </div>

    </xp:div>
```

Seems valid to me. I have implemented the dojo styles via a theme, because it seemed like it hasn't been done autmatically. All needed pictures are imported, too.

The result on my page is, the place where the ThumbnailPicker should be, there is just nothing, in the code there is, but nothing is displayed. Below that, I get the box for the Slideshow with the buttons in it, but no pictures.

Do you have an idea what may have gone wrong or does that simply not work in XPages for some reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to

```
<script type="dojo/connect">
```

part. I had some browser-specific problems with dojo/connect events. Instead, you may try adding the following CS JavaScript to onClientLoad of the XPage/custom control:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
  var itemRequest = { query: {}, count: 20 };
  var itemNameMap = { imageThumbAttr: "label", imageLargeAttr: "name" };
  dijit.byId('gallery1').setDataStore(imageItemStore, itemRequest, itemNameMap);
});
```